# How to set intervals of time in RRule?

Tags: rrule

What is the syntax to describe an event with an interval of time.
For example ,

> from April 6 to April 12 2022, between 10:00 and 12:00

Is it possible to set it using the online tool ?
https://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/